# jQuery Confirm in CFSelect Box Without Submitting Form

Tags: jquery, validation, coldfusion

I'm trying to get the form to throw an alert when the admin selects 'Process' from the drop down that reads "Are you sure you want to process?". There is also code to verify that either 'Process' or 'Reject' has been selected. Nothing is supposed to happen when the admin clicks 'Reject'. This is what I have thus far.

```
   <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="datatables.min.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="datatables.min.js"></script>
     <script>
$(document).Check(function () {

$("#ToBeProcessed").change(function () {

if ($(this).val() == "Process") {
   alert("Are you sure you want to process?");
}
elseif ($(this).val() == "") {
}
   alert("You must process or reject the changes to this invoice.");
   return false;
});
});
</script>    
</head>

<body>
<cfform name="ToBeProcessed" id="ToBeProcessed" action="ToBeProcessed.cfm?Invoice=#Invoice#" preservedata="yes" method="post">
<cfoutput>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Approved By: &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
        #qryGetToBeProcessed.Approved_Username#
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Approved Date: &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
        #DateFormat(qryGetToBeProcessed.Approved_Date,"MM/DD/YYYY")#
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        To Be Processed: &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
        <cfselect name="ToBeProcessed" id="ToBeProcessed" style="Padding: 2px;" onchange="Check()">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="Process">Process</option>
            <option value="Rejected">Rejected</option>
        </cfselect>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="2" style="Padding:3px;">
        <cfinput type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Save"> 
        <input type="Button" name="Back" value="Cancel" onclick="window.history.back()">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</cfoutput>
</cfform>

</body>
```

Comment: What actually happens when you run the code above?

Comment: What's `$(document).Check` - is that something added in by cfform?

Comment: Not related to your question, but onChange events on selects might not work the way you intended if the user uses his keyboard instead of his mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
elseif ($(this).val() == "") {
```

There is no `elseif` in Javascript.  You're probably getting a JS error.  Check your console, and then change it to:

```
else if ($(this).val() == "") {
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else#Using_else_if

Also it looks like you've got another syntax error here with an additional closing `}` after that elseif which will also cause you an error:

```
elseif ($(this).val() == "") {
}  <--- WHAT'S THIS HERE FOR?
   alert("You must process or reject the changes to this invoice.");
```

Here's a rewrite that should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ToBeProcessed").on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Process") {
           alert("Are you sure you want to process?");
        }
        else if ($(this).val() == "") {
           alert("You must process or reject the changes to this invoice.");
        }
    });
});
```

... and you should be able to remove the `onchange="Check()"` from the `<cfselect>` as the jQuery `.on('change')` should cover that.

Comment: Yes, I missed that bracket at the end. I'd been trying different solutions and must have left that in.  I chose to use your rewrite and I removed the onchange from the cfeselect. It worked perfectly.  Thank you!